# Getting multiple matches in a hierarchical string using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here is my string:

> ((A_1:2,B:3):2.1,C_3:1.2,(D:3,(E:4.3,F:2):3.1,):G:1.7);

I need to be able to capture any and all sets of parentheses pairs e.g.

> (A_1:2,B:3)

and

> (D:3,(E:4.3,F:2):3.1,)

This:

```
\([^ ]+\)
```

will capture the entire string, but I can't find a combination of group systems that will capture at least 10 levels of nested parentheses pairs.

I hope to be able to put the captured groups into a data structure so I can parse it more easily. But first, I need to capture the pairs.

Comment: you want to capture all (...) inside () ? and skip rest yes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: Well, everything is in at least one (), so there is nothing to skip.

Comment: You may get what you need with PyPi regex module. Not with the standard re module.

Comment: I edited it. I don't need an that many levels of nested pairs.

Comment: What is target output ? array with all matches?
Is this ok? `["(A_1:2,B:3)","(D:3,(E:4.3,F:2):3.1,)"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need regex for this event more it's harder with.
Here's what i came up with:
*Asuming your target datatype is array of stings*

```
def split(data):
    temp = ""
    data = data[1:-2]
    array = []
    closed = opened = 0
    for letter in data:
        if letter == '(':
            opened += 1
        elif letter == ')':
            closed += 1

        if opened != 0:
            temp += letter
            if opened == closed:
                array.append(temp)
                temp = ""
                opened = 0
                closed = 0
    return array

print(split("((A_1:2,B:3):2.1,C_3:1.2,(D:3,(E:4.3,F:2):3.1,):G:1.7);"))
```

Comment: I can work with an array of strings. 


This results in:
['(A_1:2,B:3)', '(D:3,(E:4.3,F:2):3.1,)']



(D:3,(E:4.3,F:2):3.1,) still needs to be split off.



I assume if I want to go another level, I just run the function again, but on the second element in the array?

Comment: So is it fine ? I can change it but you have to specify output.

Comment: @Glubbdrubb yes it would work but then you have to remove this `data = data[1:-2]` and use is at firs data because for this to work input must be `(A_1:2,B:3):2.1,C_3:1.2,(D:3,(E:4.3,F:2):3.1,):G:1.7` so without first brackets thats done by `data = data[1:-2]` if you want to use this function recursivly then you have to remove this fragment

Comment: That's great! :D  
Would be nice if you accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with regexp matching.  The reason is because the language of all matching parenthesized strings is not regular.  Look at some bibliography of pattern matching and finite automata, and you'll find the mathematical reasoning behind this.